# How to get Attachement Ids of sobjects for saleforce?

Tags: rest-api, attachment

How to get Attachement Ids of sobjects for saleforce?

I am already attached one pdf file in one of my Account object then also its not showing here.
attachement is added as a notes.
I am not getting attachement in sobjects/attachment rest APi.

```
{
    "objectDescribe": {
        "activateable": false,
        "createable": true,
        "custom": false,
        "customSetting": false,
        "deepCloneable": false,
        "deletable": true,
        "deprecatedAndHidden": false,
        "feedEnabled": false,
        "hasSubtypes": false,
        "isInterface": false,
        "isSubtype": false,
        "keyPrefix": "00P",
        "label": "Attachment",
        "labelPlural": "Attachments",
        "layoutable": false,
        "mergeable": false,
        "mruEnabled": false,
        "name": "Attachment",
        "queryable": true,
        "replicateable": true,
        "retrieveable": true,
        "searchable": true,
        "triggerable": true,
        "undeletable": true,
        "updateable": true,
        "urls": {
            "rowTemplate": "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Attachment/{ID}",
            "defaultValues": "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Attachment/defaultValues?recordTypeId&fields",
            "describe": "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Attachment/describe",
            "sobject": "/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Attachment"
        }
    },
    "recentItems": []
}
```

Comment: This is a Describe API response body, not a query or retrieve. Please [edit] your post to show detailed steps you are using to obtain Attachment information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notes and Attachments are two different objects, like Tasks and Events are located in Activities. You can use `/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/Note` to get "classic" notes, and `/services/data/v50.0/sobjects/ContentNote` to get the new Enhanced Notes. Querying Attachments will only show files.